# Hibernate query return userId='null'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I want to create login system with Servlet, JSP and Hibernate. But I receive an error, userId ='null'. Used Java classes are below. Could you  help me please?

Query Result:

> Hibernate: select users0_.id as id0_, users0_.email as email0_,
>   users0_.firstName as firstName0_, users0_.lastName as lastName0_,
>   users0_.middleName as middleName0_, users0_.password as password0_,
>   users0_.userId as userId0_ from users users0_ where
>   users0_.userId='null'

This query result return duplicate.

Login Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = {"/Login"})
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException { 
     String userId = request.getParameter("userId");    
     String password = request.getParameter("password");
     LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
     boolean result = loginService.authenticate(userId, password);
     Users user = loginService.getUserByUserId(userId);
     if(result == true){
         request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);       
         response.sendRedirect("deneme.jsp");
     }
     else{
         response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
     }
}
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
     processRequest(request, response);
}
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
     processRequest(request, response);
}
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
     return "Short description";
 }
}
```

User Model:

```
Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String userId;
private String password;

//Constructor and Getter Setter methods 
}
```

Login Service:

```
public class LoginService {
public boolean authenticate(String userId, String password) {
     Users user = getUserByUserId(userId);      
     if(user!=null && user.getUserId().equals(userId) && user.getPassword().equals(password)){
         return true;
     }else{
         return false;
     }
}
public Users getUserByUserId(String userId) {
     Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
     Transaction tx = null;
     Users user = null;
     try {
         tx = session.getTransaction();
         tx.begin();
         Query query = session.createQuery("from Users where userId='"+userId+"'");
         user = (Users)query.uniqueResult();
         tx.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         if (tx != null) {
             tx.rollback();
         }
         e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
         session.close();
     }
     return user;
}

public List<Users> getListOfUsers(){
     List<Users> list = new ArrayList<Users>();
     Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
     Transaction tx = null; 
     try {
         tx = session.getTransaction();
         tx.begin();
         list = session.createQuery("from Users").list();                   
         tx.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         if (tx != null) {
             tx.rollback();
         }
         e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
         session.close();
     }
     return list;
}
}
```

Hibernate Util:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
         try {
             sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
         } catch (Throwable ex) {
             System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
             throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
         }
    }

    public static Session openSession() {
         return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
  }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
         <property name="show_sql">true</property>
         <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
         <mapping class="com.bookstore.model.Users" />
    </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

login.jsp

```
<!-- Account Login-->

              <div align="right">
              <form role="form" action="login" method="post" >

                       <label  class="control-label">User Id:</label>                
                      <input type="text" name="userId"  class="span3">
                    <label  class="control-label"  >Password:</label>                  
                      <input type="password" name="password">  

                        <input type="submit" value="Login" >
              </form>
          </div>
```

Comment: pleas share login.jsp

Comment: In your servlet just check whether your are getting the value of userId. you are doing String userId = request.getParameter("userId"); . Just do a Sytem.out.println(userId); and check the value.

Comment: As far as I know, URL are case sensitive. But in your case, the `action` attribute of your form is `login` while your servlet is mapped to `Login`. Does the call function at all?

Answer (score -1):

Login servlet can be called in two ways either doPost or doGet. If it is doGet then use request.getParameter("userId") or if it is post form submit then use request.getAttribute("userId"). Lets us know how you are invoking your login servlet.